# google-api-php-client Library crashing after cleanup command

Tags: php, wordpress, firebase, push-notification, google-client

I am using the google-api-php-client for integrating the firebase API, I'm only using the core
client function and not using the dedicated library in apiclient-services which comes with the google-api-php-client library,

so I used the cleanup command as per the documentation to clear the unnecessary libraries, but when I try to run the code it crashes, and getting the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Class "Monolog\Logger" not found in /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-content/plugins/push-notifications-for-wordpress-custom/vendor/google-api-php-client-main/src/Client.php:1159 
Stack trace: #0 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-content/plugins/push-notifications-for-wordpress-custom/vendor/google-api-php-client-main/src/Client.php(1151): Google\Client->createDefaultLogger() 
#1 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-content/plugins/push-notifications-for-wordpress-custom/vendor/google-api-php-client-main/src/Client.php(319): Google\Client->getLogger() 
#2 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-content/plugins/push-notifications-for-wordpress-custom/includes/notifications/class-pnfw-notifications-android.php(73): Google\Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion() 
#3 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-content/plugins/push-notifications-for-wordpress-custom/includes/notifications/class-pnfw-notifications.php(115): PNFW_Notifications_Android->raw_send(Array, 'This is a test ...', Array) 
#4 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-content/plugins/push-notifications-for-wordpress-custom/admin/class-pnfw-admin-tokens.php(86): PNFW_Notifications->send_title_to_tokens('This is a test ...', Array) 
#5 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-content/plugins/push-notifications-for-wordpress-custom/admin/class-pnfw-admin.php(203): PNFW_Admin_Tokens::output() 
#6 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): PNFW_Admin->tokens_page('') 
#7 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) 
#8 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#9 /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action('push-notificati...') 
#10 {main} thrown in /home/schoolsa/public_html/push/wp-content/plugins/push-notifications-for-wordpress-custom/vendor/google-api-php-client-main/src/Client.php on line 1159
```

Github URL for the library
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

The monolog\monolog is part of google-api-php-client and is installed as a dependency for the core library. not for the apiclient-services